# Cannot Push png files to Github Repository LFS Error

Tags: git, github

I have been pushing png and image files fine to github. Now, I get an error.

My set up: Windows + Visual Studio Code + git bash for terminal

This is my .git/config file

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[credential]
    helper = store
[lfs "https://github.com/ryan/restart.git/info/lfs"]
    locksverify = false
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/ryan/restart.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
```

So I add an image to my repository.

I do

```
git add .
git commit
git push
```

This is what git push results:

```
guestaccount@LAPTOP-4G5S6I9K MINGW64 /c/xampp7.2/htdocs/folder2-temp (main)
$ git push
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/guestaccount/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s
```

I always seem to get stuck here then this shows:

```
$ git push
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/guestaccount/.ssh/id_rsa': 
batch request: ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out: exit status 255
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://github.com/ryan/restart.git'
```

I have been asking how to switch from SSH to https in order to solve the problem, but it seems that's not the issue.

[Cannot reset github from ssh to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67246815/cannot-reset-github-from-ssh-to-https)

So, basically how do I upload png files again? This particular png file is only 46KB so github should be able to push it.

Comment: This looks like an authentication problem, plain and simple. Can you push _anything_ to this repo? It sounds like you have not shared your public key with the remote server. (And it seems to me very dubious that if you're on a "guest account" you would have any SSH access to anything.)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I titled my account (on Windows my laptop) guest account. But it has administrator privileges. I have been able to push almost everything else to github except for png files. When I push png files or images it gets stuck at "Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s" then returns an error like discussed above.

Comment: non images are pushed quickly and efficiently. Before I was able to upload images too. So far I have uploaded 94 commits. Someone had a prestashop site live and wanted me to put it on github. So I have been uploading slowly. Almost everything else is uploaded except a few images.

Comment: I don't know LFS but maybe all images are now going to the LFS server, and that's the one you have not authenticated to.

Comment: Thank you. How would I fix that?

Comment: I don't know, but in your previous q. you quoted Git as saying `Permission denied (publickey)`, which sounds to me like you're talking to a server that doesn't know your public key.

Comment: I'm so confused. So github knows my public key but LFS does not? I guess I have to authenticate SSH to LFS server. Just don't know how. Thank you matt

Comment: I don't know either; I don't know where the LFS server is. But I believe the point of LFS is that some files live elsewhere, namely the LFS server. This is all just guesswork on my part, based on the info you've given.

Comment: How would I disable LFS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699293/how-to-i-disable-git-lfs

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try. I do appreciate your time and have upvoted all your answers, if that helps in any way.

Comment: No need for that; these are comments, not answers, and we are just chatting. Remember, I know nothing of LFS.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue (stuck on "Uploading LFS objects"). Further investigating, setting the environment variables `GIT_TRACE=1` and `GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1`.

I noticed that the git is stuck at the following:

```sh
run_command: C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -- git@my-git-domain.com git-lfs-authenticate my-git-repository.git upload
trace git-lfs: exec: C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe '--' 'git@my-git-domain.com' 'git-lfs-authenticate my-git-repository.git upload'
```

Surprisingly, running the following command successfully returned and displayed my authorization header.

```sh
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -- git@my-git-domain.com git-lfs-authenticate my-git-repository.git upload
```

Turns out that the [shipped Win10 ssh client has a bug](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4315#issuecomment-732385550) and [downloading a new version](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/) and setting the following environment variable resolved the issue.

```
GIT_SSH=C:\MyPath\to\the\new\ssh.exe
```